# ApplicationEndPoint in UCMA applications

Tags: c#, .net, lync, ucma, ucma2.0

I have an application which uses UCMA for getting the status of the lync users.

I have a clarification . I have downloaded the sample application which inherits a class as follows:

```
public class UcPresenceProvider : Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Samples.HTMLPresenceControls.Service.IPresenceProvider
    {

  public UcPresenceProvider(ApplicationEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            m_applicationEndpoint = endpoint;
        }
}
```

From a layman's point of view, what will be the value for the ApplicationEndpoint endpoint would be .

I just need the status of a logged in user thats it .

Answer (score 1):

check this out ...

```
// Gateway participant that impersonates a phone user
// _gatewayEndpoint = _helper.CreateApplicationEndpoint(
// "GatewayParticipant" /*endpointFriendlyName*/);

public ApplicationEndpoint CreateApplicationEndpoint(string contactFriendlyName)
    {
        string prompt = string.Empty;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contactFriendlyName))
        {
            contactFriendlyName = "Default Contact";
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Creating Application Endpoint {0}...", contactFriendlyName);
        Console.WriteLine();

        // If application settings are provided via the app.config file, then use them
        // Else prompt user for details
        if (!ReadApplicationContactConfiguration())
        {
            // Prompt user for server FQDN. If server FQDN was entered before, then let the user use the saved value.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_serverFqdn))
            {
                prompt = "Please enter the FQDN of the Microsoft Lync Server for this topology => ";
                _serverFqdn = PromptUser(prompt, null);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_applicationHostFQDN))
            {
                prompt = "Please enter the FQDN of the Machine that the application service is configured to => ";
                _applicationHostFQDN = PromptUser(prompt, null);
            }
            if (0 >= _applicationPort)
            {
                // Prompt user for contact port
                prompt = "Please enter the port that the application service is configured to => ";
                _applicationPort = int.Parse(PromptUser(prompt, null), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_applicationGruu))
            {
                // Prompt user for Contact GRUU
                prompt = "Please enter the GRUU assigned to the application service => ";
                _applicationGruu = PromptUser(prompt, null);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_applicationContactURI))
            {
                // Prompt user for contact URI
                prompt = "Please enter the Contact URI in the User@Host format => ";
                _applicationContactURI = PromptUser(prompt, null);
                if (!_applicationContactURI.Trim().StartsWith(_sipPrefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    _applicationContactURI = _sipPrefix + _applicationContactURI.Trim();
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_certificateFriendlyName))
            {
                // Prompt user for contact URI
                prompt = "Please enter the friendly name of the certificate to be used => ";
                _certificateFriendlyName = PromptUser(prompt, null);
            }
        }

        // Reuse platform instance so that all endpoints share the same platform.
        if (_serverCollabPlatform == null)
        {
            CreateAndStartServerPlatform();
        }

        // Initalize and register the endpoint.
        // NOTE: the _applicationContactURI should always be of the form "sip:user@host"
        ApplicationEndpointSettings appEndpointSettings = new ApplicationEndpointSettings(_applicationContactURI, _serverFqdn, 5061);
        _applicationEndpoint = new ApplicationEndpoint(_serverCollabPlatform, appEndpointSettings);
        _endpointInitCompletedEvent.Reset();

        Console.WriteLine("Establishing the endpoint...");
        _applicationEndpoint.BeginEstablish(EndEndpointEstablish, _applicationEndpoint);

        // Sync; wait for the registration to complete.
        _endpointInitCompletedEvent.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Application Endpoint established...");
        return _applicationEndpoint;
    }
```

Comment: <add key="ServerFQDN" value="LyncServer2013.telesign.local" /> 

<!-- <add key="ApplicationHostFQDN" value="appmachine.contoso.com"/> -->
<add key="ApplicationHostFQDN" value="PoolServer2013.telesign.local" />

<add key="ApplicationPort" value="10600" />

Comment: <!-- The GRUU that the application contact is assigned. -->
<!-- <add key="ApplicationGRUU" value="sip:user.contoso.com@contoso.com;gruu;opaque=srvr:service:uRYqodmwaFSSHo0TQSUv7QAA"/> -->
<add key="ApplicationGRUU" value="sip:aplicacao.telesign.local@telesign.local;gruu;opaque=srvr:service:uRYqodmwaFSSHo0TQSUv7QAA" />

Comment: <!-- <add key="ApplicationContactURI1" value="user@host"/> -->
    <add key="ApplicationContactURI1" value="aplicacao2@telesign.local" />    
 
<!-- Provide the friendly name of the certificate that should be used to communicate with the server. -->
    <!-- The sample looks for a matching cert in the LocalComputer/Personal store. -->
    <add key="CertificateFriendlyName" value="Lync Pool Server 2013 Certificate" />

Answer (score 0):

It will be one of the trusted application endpoints you have added to this UCMA application when you provisioned it on the SfB/Lync.

If you are only interested in the presence of a single user then it maybe that the UCMA is overkill, you may want to consider using the Client SDK.